# How this asynchronous test suite built in JavaScript will terminate?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timer

The following is an implementation of how to implement a test suite that performs asynchronous testing using a *central timer control* from the book [Secrets of JavaScript Ninja](http://www.amazon.in/Secrets-JavaScript-Ninja-John-Resig/dp/193398869X) by Jon Resig.

```
      (function() {

        var queue = [], paused = false;                //#1

        this.test = function(fn) {                     //#2
          queue.push(fn);
          runTest();
        };

        this.pause = function() {                      //#3
          paused = true;
        };

        this.resume = function() {                     //#4
          paused = false;
          setTimeout(runTest, 1);
        };

        function runTest() {                           //#5
          if (!paused && queue.length) {
            queue.shift()();
            if (!paused) resume();
          }
        }
      })();
```

And this how the author is setting the `test()` function to its paces:

```
      test(function() {
        pause();
        setTimeout(function() {
          assert(true, "First test completed");
          resume();
        }, 100);
      });

      test(function() {
        pause();
        setTimeout(function() {
          assert(true, "Second test completed");
          resume();
        }, 200);
      });

    </script>
```

I understand that every *function* pushed into the *queue* needs to call `pause()` before the asynchronous call and needs to call `resume()` after the asynchronous call is over. 
But I fail to see how the test suite will end itself. At the end of the last test the value of `pause` flag will be false because the last test would have called `resume()` after finishing itself and resume in turn calls `runTest()` with a `setTimeout()`. Seems to me like an infinite loop. Can some one explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> […] resume in turn calls `runTest()` with a `setTimeout()`.

Yes, but then `runTest()` doesn't do anything (since `queue.length` will be `0`, which is falsy): no new test is run, no further calls to `resume()`, nothing.

Comment: But  if `(!paused) resume()` will again call `resume()` . Isn't it ?

Comment: @Geek: No, because that's nested inside the `if (!paused && queue.length)` block.

Comment: Ah I see. Not sure how I overlooked that.